# Left For Dead Characters

Tags: left-4-dead-series

Are the characters in Left For Dead 1 and 2 modeled after real-life people?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "modeled after real-life people".

If you mean visually, then yes! Valve usually models the face of their characters based on some real-life person (probably a hired model or actor, but I can't confirm this). From [Left4Dead Wikia](http://left4dead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Survivors), here is a list of the face models for each character (as well as the voice actor):

| Game | Character | Face model | Voice actor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| L4D1 | Bill | Bernard Fouquet | Jim French |
| L4D1 | Francis | Taylor Knox | Vince Valenzuela |
| L4D1 | Louis | Sean Bennett | Earl Alexander |
| L4D1 | Zoey | Sonja Kinski | Jen Taylor |
| L4D2 | Coach | Darnell Rice | Chad Coleman |
| L4D2 | Ellis | Jesy McKinney | Eric Ladin |
| L4D2 | Nick | Taymour Ghazi | Hugh Dillon |
| L4D2 | Rochelle | Shanola Hampton | Rochelle Aytes |

The body is easier to model in 3D, and is probably based on sketches made by Valve artists. However, it is very difficult to accurately model a face, and that's why they use real-life models for faces. (but, of course, they fine-tune the modelled face to fit better to the character, like the [G-Man](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/G-Man) from Half-Life series)

Comment: Valve often uses real people as models for their in-game characters.  Dr. Vance is modeled after a homeless person (http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Eli_Vance#Behind_the_scenes).  More: http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs38/f/2008/363/1/0/Half_Life_2_Character_Models_by_leebyrne.jpg

Answer (score 2):

It appears that they are just stereotypes:

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_4_Dead)

> There are four playable human characters in the game: Francis, a ***stereotypical*** biker (voiced by Vince Valenzuela); Bill, a Vietnam Veteran (voiced by Jim French); Zoey, a university student (voiced by Jen Taylor); and Louis, a district Account Manager (voiced by Earl Alexander).

(my emphasis)

However, I wouldn't be surprised if each characters appearance wasn't based on a real-life person - but that person could be anyone, even one of the developers!